# Django: Cannot update foreign key values in a model

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I create **this model**, the values are nulls.

```
class TestRequest(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "TestRequest"

    title = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True, blank=True)
    testConfiguration = models.ForeignKey(
        TestConfiguration, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
    testDescription = models.ForeignKey(
        TestDescription, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True, blank=True)
```

**The serializer:**

```
class TestRequestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = TestRequest
        fields = [
            'id',
            'title',
            'testConfiguration',
            'testDescription',
        ]
        depth = 2
```

**The view:**

```
@api_view(['PUT'])
def TestRequestUpdate(request, pk):
    testRequest = TestRequest.objects.get(id=pk)
    serializer = TestRequestSerializer(instance=testRequest, data=request.data)

    if serializer.is_valid():
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)

    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And when I want to update them later from the front-end with **this state**:

```
id: 98
title: "title"
testConfiguration: 31
testDescription: 32
```

I get **this response**:

```
{
   "id": 98,
   "title": "title",
   "testConfiguration": null,
   "testDescription": null
}
```

Why can't I update it?

**EDIT:** I added my solution as an answer.

Comment: Are you sure that testConfiguration: 31 and testDescription: 32 are already existing in your DB?

Comment: Yes im sure, I copied it from the console, so it isn't just some random numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was that i removed the depth value from the serializer for the POST requests and added a separate serializer with the depth value for the GET requests.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your views with the following code:

```
testRequest = TestRequest.objects.get(id=pk)

import json

data = json.loads(json.dumps(request.data))

if data.get('testConfiguration', None) is None and testRequest.testConfiguration:
    data.update({'testConfiguration': testRequest.testConfiguration.id})

if data.get('testDescription', None) is None and testRequest.testDescription:
    data.update({'testDescription': testRequest.testDescription.id})

serializer = TestRequestSerializer(instance=testRequest, data=data)
```